# What is the 3rd and 4th value in the hardforks.cpp?

Tags: blockchain, hard-fork

I know what the first two values are. Version and then block height.
But then there is a third value with nothing then the fourth value which contains a very long number, I do not know what it means.

The third value and fourth value in this:

```
  { 1, 1, 0, 1341378000 }
```

Is it seconds? What is the seconds for?
What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third value is unused.

The fourth value is indeed seconds, and was used to display a "you need to update" message after about 6 months from that date, since Monero used to fork  every six months. This warning is not removed, since it'd trigger pointlessly as we fork less often now, and without a constant schedule.

Comment: What is the seconds counting FROM though?

Comment: The canonical UNIX epoch, first of January 1970.